# Remote validation shows error message but still lets the form submit and saves in database MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations

The situation is, combination of **Student Reg. No.** and **Select Course** is always unique.

Upon selection of a combination which was saved before in database, the expected results are,

**First Expected Result:**

Error message “Selected Student has taken this course already” will appear.

**Second Expected Result:**

It will refrain the form from submitting until a different combination is selected which was not saved in database before.

**Current Result:**

First Expected Result is working well:

[image]

But, the Second Expected Result is not working. That is, it submits the form and saves the combination which was already saved in database before.

Can you please give a solution as I can get the Second Expected Result?

Thanks in advance.

For readability I have excluded all codes, html and scripts associated with Name, Email and Department.

Here is my Model,

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UniversityApplication.Models
{
public class CourseStudent
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Student Reg. No.")]
    public string CourseStudentRegNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsCourseNameExists", "CourseStudents", AdditionalFields = "CourseStudentRegNo", ErrorMessage = "Selected Student has taken this course already.")]
    [DisplayName("Select Course")]
    public string CourseStudentCourse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CourseStudentRegDate { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my Controller,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UniversityApplication.Context;
using UniversityApplication.Models;

namespace UniversityApplication.Controllers
{
public class CourseStudentsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();

    public ActionResult StudentToCourse()
    {
        GenerateDropDownValue();
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult StudentToCourse([Bind(Include = "CourseStudentID,CourseStudentRegNo,CourseStudentName,CourseStudentEmail,CourseStudentDepartmentCode,CourseStudentCourse,CourseStudentRegDate")] CourseStudent courseStudent)
    {
        GenerateDropDownValue();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CoursesStudents.Add(courseStudent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();

            return View();
        }
        ModelState.Clear();

        return View();            
    }

private void GenerateDropDownValue()
    {
        List<Student> allRegisteredStudents = new List<Student>();
        List<SelectListItem> students = new List<SelectListItem>();

        List<Course> allCourses = new List<Course>();


        string studentName = "";
        string studentEmail = "";
        string studentDepartment = "";

        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            allRegisteredStudents = db.Students.OrderBy(a => a.StudentRegNo).ToList();
        }

        foreach (var student in allRegisteredStudents)
        {
            students.Add(

                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = student.StudentRegNo,
                    Text = student.StudentRegNo
                }
                );
        }

        ViewBag.Students = students;
        ViewBag.CourseCode = new SelectList(allCourses, "CourseCode", "CourseName");
        ViewBag.StudentName = studentName;
        ViewBag.StudentEmail = studentEmail;
        ViewBag.StudentDepartment = studentDepartment;
    }

    public JsonResult IsCourseNameExists(string CourseStudentCourse, string CourseStudentRegNo)
    {
        return Json(!db.CoursesStudents.Any(x => x.CourseStudentCourse == CourseStudentCourse && x.CourseStudentRegNo == CourseStudentRegNo), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }    

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my View,

```
@model UniversityApplication.Models.CourseStudent

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>CourseStudent</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseStudentRegNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseStudentRegNo, @ViewBag.Students as SelectList, "Select Student", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseStudentRegNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>        

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseStudentCourse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourseStudentCourse, @ViewBag.CourseCode as SelectList, "Select Course", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseStudentCourse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseStudentRegDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CourseStudentRegDate, new { @class = "date form-control", @readonly = "true" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseStudentRegDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Enroll" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section Scripts {

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.date.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
</script>

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Custom Remote Validation via the JsonResult method `IsCourseNameExists` I would recommend implementing your validation via **Custom Data Annotations**.

**Refer** this link on how to create your custom validation via Data Annotation: [Custom Validation Data Annotation Attribute](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/)

Using this if the validation does not succeed then you will have Invalid Model State and you will need not worry about the error. It also makes your architecture more secure.

**Additionally,** as a best practice, you should also have the same check (that you are doing in `IsCourseNameExists` method) on the server side in your controller, right before you are saving to the database. **Note:** If you only implement this check even then your requirement gets fulfilled.

Comment: Sorry For late reply. Your solution worked great and made my application more secure. And, I have also found the solution of my question.

Comment: How does a custom validation attribute provide more security over the `[Remote]` attribute? As far as I know, when a form is submitted to the server to be saved to the database, the `[Remote]` attribute runs validation again.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

I missed to add

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

above scripts on top of my cshtml file.

It looks like,

```
@model UniversityApplication.Models.CourseStudent

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

//Rest codes
```